# Interface serialization

Tags: java, serialization, interface

Im trying to serialize an interface object that i have instantiated and implemented the methods for,for a problem and im getting the following errors,It seems that it writes something to the file but i get the exception nonetheless
---the code is updated---
The interface

```
package ro.axonsoft.internship21.pay;

import ro.axonsoft.internship21.error.PayError;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public interface PayMetrics extends Serializable {
    BigDecimal averagePaymentAmount();
    Integer bigPayments();
    Integer smallPayments();
    Integer paymentsByMinors();
    BigDecimal totalAmountCapitalCity();
    Integer foreigners();
    PayError[] errors();
}
```

and the implementatio and serialization

```
 package ro.axonsoft.internship21.pay;

import ro.axonsoft.internship21.cnp.CnpException;
import ro.axonsoft.internship21.cnp.CnpParts;
import ro.axonsoft.internship21.cnp.CnpValidatorImpl;
import ro.axonsoft.internship21.cnp.Judet;
import ro.axonsoft.internship21.error.PayError;

import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.*;

public class PayMetricsProcessorImpl implements PayMetricsProcessor{


    @Override
    public void process(InputStream paymentsln, OutputStream metricsOut) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(paymentsln);
        List<PayError> payErrors=new LinkedList<>();
        HashMap<CnpParts,BigDecimal> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
        int nr_line=0;
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line=scanner.nextLine();
            String[] components=new String[2];
            if(line.contains(";")) {
                components=line.split(";");
                boolean price_ok=true;
                for(int i=0;i<components[1].length();i++){
                    if(Character.isLetter(components[1].charAt(i))){
                        price_ok=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!price_ok){
                    int finalNr_line = nr_line;
                    PayError payError=new PayError() {
                        @Override
                        public Integer line() {
                            return finalNr_line;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Integer type() {
                            return 2;
                        }
                    };
                    payErrors.add(payError);
                }
                else {
                    BigDecimal price=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(components[1]));
                    try {
                        CnpValidatorImpl cnpValidator=new CnpValidatorImpl();
                        CnpParts cnpParts=cnpValidator.validateCnp(components[0]);
                        hashMap.put(cnpParts,price);
                    }
                    catch (CnpException e){
                        int finalNr_line1 = nr_line;
                        PayError payError=new PayError() {
                            @Override
                            public Integer line() {
                                return finalNr_line1;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public Integer type() {
                                return 1;
                            }
                        };
                        payErrors.add(payError);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                int finalNr_line2 = nr_line;
                PayError payError=new PayError() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer line() {
                        return finalNr_line2;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Integer type() {
                        return 0;
                    }
                };
                payErrors.add(payError);
            }

            nr_line++;
        }
        scanner.close();

        ///AVERAGE PAYMENT
        BigDecimal sum=new BigDecimal(0);
        for(Map.Entry mapEl:hashMap.entrySet()){
            BigDecimal value= (BigDecimal) mapEl.getValue();
            sum=sum.add(value);
        }
        BigDecimal averagePaymentAmount=new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(sum));
        BigDecimal numitor=new BigDecimal(hashMap.size());
        averagePaymentAmount=averagePaymentAmount.divide(numitor);
        averagePaymentAmount.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);


        ///BIG PAYMENTS
        Integer bigpayments=new Integer(0);
        for(Map.Entry mapEl:hashMap.entrySet()){
            BigDecimal value= (BigDecimal) mapEl.getValue();
            if(value.intValue()>5000){
                bigpayments++;
            }
        }

        ///SMALL PAYMENTS
        Integer smallpayments=new Integer(0);
        for(Map.Entry mapEl:hashMap.entrySet()){
            BigDecimal value= (BigDecimal) mapEl.getValue();
            if(value.intValue()<=5000){
                smallpayments++;
            }
        }

        ///PAYMENTS BY MINORS
        Integer paymentsbyminors=new Integer(0);
        for(Map.Entry mapEl:hashMap.entrySet()){
            CnpParts cnpParts= (CnpParts) mapEl.getKey();
            LocalDate localDate=LocalDate.now();
            if(localDate.getYear()-cnpParts.birthDate().year()<18){
                paymentsbyminors++;
            }

        }

        ///TOTAL AMOUNT CAPABILITY

        BigDecimal totalAmountCapitalCity=new BigDecimal(0);
        for(Map.Entry mapEl:hashMap.entrySet()){
            CnpParts cnpParts= (CnpParts) mapEl.getKey();
            BigDecimal value= (BigDecimal) mapEl.getValue();
            if(cnpParts.judet()== Judet.BU){
                totalAmountCapitalCity=totalAmountCapitalCity.add(value);
            }

        }

        ///FOREIGNERS

        Integer foreigners=new Integer(0);
        for(Map.Entry mapEl:hashMap.entrySet()){
            CnpParts cnpParts= (CnpParts) mapEl.getKey();
            if(cnpParts.foreigner()){
                foreigners++;
            }

        }

        ///PAY ERRORS

        int size=payErrors.size();
        PayError[] payerros=new PayError[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            payerros[i]=payErrors.get(i);
        }


        BigDecimal finalAveragePaymentAmount = averagePaymentAmount;
        Integer finalBigpayments = bigpayments;
        Integer finalSmallpayments = smallpayments;
        Integer finalPaymentsbyminors = paymentsbyminors;
        BigDecimal finalTotalAmountCapitalCity = totalAmountCapitalCity;
        Integer finalForeigners = foreigners;
        PayMetrics payMetrics=new PayMetrics() {
            @Override
            public BigDecimal averagePaymentAmount() {
                return finalAveragePaymentAmount;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer bigPayments() {
                return finalBigpayments;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer smallPayments() {
                return finalSmallpayments;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer paymentsByMinors() {
                return finalPaymentsbyminors;
            }

            @Override
            public BigDecimal totalAmountCapitalCity() {
                return finalTotalAmountCapitalCity;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer foreigners() {
                return finalForeigners;
            }

            @Override
            public PayError[] errors() {
                return payerros;
            }
        };

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(metricsOut);
        out.writeObject(payMetrics);
        out.close();



    }
}
```

and the errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: ro.axonsoft.internship21.pay.PayMetricsProcessorImpl
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at ro.axonsoft.internship21.pay.PayMetricsProcessorImpl.process(PayMetricsProcessorImpl.java:211)
    at ro.axonsoft.internship21.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Comment: where is `PayMetricsProcessorImpl`? the code that you show is obviously not the code that you run

Comment: this serialization is in the impl class

Comment: what do you mean "you don't have it"? where does `Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: ro.axonsoft.internship21.pay.PayMetricsProcessorImpl` comes from then?

Comment: im sorry,i misread,the impl class is the present one

Comment: ill add the code now

Comment: ive added the full code

Answer (score 1):

This `PayMetrics payMetrics=new PayMetrics() {....}` will create an anonymous inner class that has an implicit reference to the outer class `PayMetricsProcessorImpl`. If you want to be able to serialize the latter, you must be able to serialize the former.

It would be so much easier for you, if you could create a *separate* class, like:

```
public class PayMetricsImpl implements PayMetrics { .... }
```

and serialize that particular instance of `PayMetricsImpl`.

Comment: if i do that ,whats the best method to send my file input to the impl class for parsing?an instance hash map of something of the sort?

Comment: sorry but I do not understand your question, and it goes beyond the initial one you had anyway.

Comment: sorry then,ill recheck